# What would be the best approach to multitenancy with .NET 6, Entity Framework and PostgreSQL?

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, multi-tenant, saas

I'm currently working on the API for a multi-tenant application, built with .NET 6 and using the Entity Framework. The project uses a PostGRES database.

All tenants are in the same database but records have a `tenant_id` field and I want to implement Row Level Security, to compartmentalise each tenant/keep their data secure and separate.

What would be the most appropriate approach for implementing RLS for multitenancy? Is it more common to provision a user for each tenant or to use the `current_setting('app.current_tenant')::UUID` value for the RLS policy?

How would either of these approaches be implemented in the Entity Framework? E.g. how would you get it to switch user every time a query is run or how would you set the `app.current_tenant` before queries? If you take the second approach, is there a risk of accidentally persisting this tenant ID across queries and potentially leaking data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters),

> Global query filters are LINQ query predicates applied to Entity Types
> in the metadata model (usually in OnModelCreating). A query predicate
> is a boolean expression typically passed to the LINQ Where query
> operator. EF Core applies such filters automatically to any LINQ
> queries involving those Entity Types. EF Core also applies them to
> Entity Types, referenced indirectly through use of Include or
> navigation property. Some common applications of this feature are:
>
> Soft delete - An Entity Type defines an IsDeleted property.
>
> Multi-tenancy - An Entity Type defines a TenantId property.

eg

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "TenantId") == _tenantId);
```

Although using a separate database per tenant is often a better approach.  At least plan to support having more than one tenant database, with some mapping of tenants to databases.

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct in understanding that this filters on the server side, not on the database?

Comment: The query filter is transformed into SQL and sent to the database.